# Django hitcount order_by("hit_count_generic__hits") gives error on PostgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql, github, hitcounter

I was using [django-hitcont](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/tree/develop/hitcount) to count the views on my Post model. I am trying to get the most viewed post in my ListView using this query `objects.order_by('hit_count_generic__hits')`  and it is working fine on SQLite but on PostgreSQL, it is giving me this error :
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer = text LINE 1: ...R JOIN "hitcount_hit_count" ON ("posts_post"."id" = "hitcoun...`.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='authors', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField('Post Title', max_length = 150)
    description = models.TextField('Description', max_length=1000, blank = True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField('Date posted', default = timezone.now)
    date_modifed = models.DateTimeField('Date last modified', default = timezone.now)
    document = models.FileField('Document of Post', upload_to='documents', \
     validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions = ['pdf', 'docx']), validate_document_size] \
    )
    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(
    HitCount,
    object_id_field='object_pk',
    related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation'
   )
```

views.py

```
queryset = Post.objects.order_by('hit_count_generic__hits')
```

I found [this](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/issues/90) issue on Github related to the problem, but I am still not able to figure out the mentioned workaround.

Comment: Can you provide the HitCountModified model? I guess the field types on the join statement mismatch.

Comment: @DenizKaplan My bad, it is HitCount only. In my database, the object_pk is text type which should be an integer. What I need is a way to change HitCount object_pk ti be an integer, but I don't know how to modify the field of HitCount in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing different types (in this example integer and text), equals operator throws this exception. To fix that, convert HitCount model pk field to integer and you are good to go. To do that, you need to create and apply migration operation. Django is a really good framework to handle this kind of operations. You just need to check values are not null and are "convertable" to integer. Just change the field type and run two commands below.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Before updating your model, I highly recommend you to take a backup in case of failure. This is not an easy operation but you can follow the these links to understand what is going on during this the process.
[migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#workflow) [dump and restore initial data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)
If you don't care the data on table, just drop table and create a brand new migration file and recreate table.

Comment: That works for now. But is there a way to do it without making changes in the hit counter library, because running "pip install requirements.txt" will override the changes in the future. Or, I have to wait for this issue to be fixed by the owner of the library.

Comment: You need to wait for a patch or you can spesify a working version in your requirements file. As far as I read from project github page, it will be better to choose second option. You can also fork the project and update on your own.